# Could not find gradle-jaxb-plugin-1.3.6.jar (com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6)

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb

I started to receive the following error in my java project which has dependencies to com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6:

```
   > Could not find gradle-jaxb-plugin-1.3.6.jar (com.github.jacobono:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.6).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/1.3.6/gradle-jaxb-plugin-1.3.6.jar
   > Could not find gradle-xsd-wsdl-slurping-1.1.2.jar (com.github.jacobono:gradle-xsd-wsdl-slurping:1.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/jacobono/gradle-xsd-wsdl-slurping/1.1.2/gradle-xsd-wsdl-slurping-1.1.2.jar
```

Not sure why this dependency is not found anymore, does anyone know how to solve this?

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you